# User Story State Change to Update Work Items

Tags: azure-devops

We're currently using Azure DevOps to manage work items (user stories, task , etc.). I'd like enable an event/trigger when I close the user story, the child task-status are also closed. Is this possible?

I saw within

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 1):

> User Story State Change to Update Work Items

Generally, we would like convert the parent work item state based on the linked child work item state, not the other way around.

Converting the child work item state based on the linked parent work item state may cause some unsafe issue. For example, if we have one child work item that is not completed, then  we accidentally closed the parent work item. In this case, the incomplete child work item will also be closed incorrectly.

To resolve auto change parent states, there is a free solution on the marketplace available: [TFS Aggregator](https://tfsaggregator.github.io//), For VSTS, you need to use Web Hook to complete it. Please refer to this : https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator-webhooks.

Besides, if auto change the linked child work item states is your final requirement, You can use the Rest API to invoke state changes. You could check the [post](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=336) and the [post](https://oshamrai.wordpress.com/2019/02/19/automation-of-state-changing-for-azure-devops-work-items-based-on-states-of-child-work-items/) for some more details.

Hope this helps.